# Overriding duplicate file in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a class `foo` which defines a file `flibbitfile.conf`. All is good.

However, I now need to define `foo-specialized` which has its own unique and special `flibbitfile.conf`.

```
class foo-specialized {
   include foo
   file { "/etc/flibbitfile.conf" :
         source => "puppet:///modules/foo-specialized/flibbitfile.conf" 
  }
}
```

As the reader has noticed, this results in a DuplicateFile error on Puppet's end.

What is the *simplest* solution here that does *not* involve rewriting/refactoring `foo` or adding significant machinery here?

Puppet version 2.7.9

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Both `foo` and `foo-specialized` cannot both manage a file with the same filesystem path.

Comment: @ptierno - My goal is that I want `foo-specialized` to take over management of that file, in a classic OO specialization approach

Comment: that won't happen. the `file` resources `namevar` is the `path` to the file. The `namevar` must be unique.

Comment: @ptierno okay, so how do I force it to happen?  it can be a dirty dirty hack.

Answer (score 2):

[Puppet inheritance](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/lang_classes.html#inheritance) to the rescue:

```
class foo-specialized inherits foo {
   File["/etc/flibbitfile.conf"] {
         source => "puppet:///modules/foo-specialized/flibbitfile.conf" 
  }
}
```

Comment: This! But don't use dashes in class names.